# Finding $n^{th}$ derivative of $x^2\log x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the nth derivative of $x^2 \log x$ and to do that I tried just differentiating the function with the hope of finding a pattern. So I did the following:
$f'(x) = 2x\log x + x$
$f''(x) = 2\log x + 3$
$f'''(x) = 2/x$
$f''''(x) = -2/x^2$

and, unfortunately, I could not spot any pattern. I also thought of applying Leibniz's theorem:

[image]

but I am not sure how I could simplify the expression when subbing $\log x$ as $u$ and $x^2$ as $v$.

Could anyone advise if there is another method of solving this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: You know that $f^{(3)}(x)=2x^{-1}$ -- pretend that's the beginning and just start from that point.

Comment: If I assume the 3rd derivative to be the beginning, then I obtain f^(n) (x) = {2*(-1)^(n-1) *(n-1)!}/{x^(n)}.However, I do not quite understand how I can incorporate the first three derivatives that we neglected into the equation.

Comment: The expression in Liebnitz' theorem (for general u,v) , will not simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the OP's question may really have been how to incorporate all the $f^{(n)}\text{'s}$ into a single formula, since $f, f',$ and $f''$ don't seem to follow the same pattern as the later ones.

Usually the answer would simply be written in cases, like

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 \log x,&\text{if }n=0,
\\2x \log x+x, &\text{if }n=1,
\\2\log x +3, &\text{if }n=2,
\\2(-1)^{n+1}(n-3)!x^{2-n},&\text{if }n\ge 3,
\end{cases}$$

without trying to come up with some artificial formula that covers $n=0, 1,$ and $2$ also.

---

If you *really* want to try to merge these, the best way would be to write

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{2-n}}{(2-n)!}(2 \log x - 2 H_{2-n}+3),&\text{if }n\le 2,
\\2(-1)^{n+1}(n-3)!x^{2-n},&\text{if }n\ge 3,
\end{cases}$$

where $\,H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}\,$ is the $\,n^{\text{th}}$ harmonic number, because then the formula even works for negative integer values of $n,$ with $\,f^{(-n)}(x)\,$ being an $n^{\text{th}}$ antiderivative of $\,f(x).$  (This still has two cases though, and I don't see a natural way to merge them into one.)

But if this was a homework problem, as I assume it was, this complicated formula isn't what was intended. And if you really only need the derivatives, it's overkill!

Comment: You could also write $2\left( -1\right)^{n+1}\left( n-3\right)!\left( 1-\delta_{n0}-\delta_{n1}-\delta_{n2}\right)x^{2-n}+\left( x^2\delta_{n0}+2x\delta_{n1}+2\delta_{n2}\right)\ln x+x\delta_{n1}+3\delta_{n2}$, with $\delta_{nk}$ the Kronecker delta function.

Comment: @J.G. True, and you could also replace $-2H_{2-n}+3$ in my second formula with $n(n+1)/2$ if you only care about $n=0, 1,$ and $2.$  But that's what I meant by an artificial formula. It just obscures what's going on -- a natural formula gives clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Though @MitchellSpector gave *the* solution, here is how it (laboriously) works with Leibnitz:

$$(uv)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nku^{(n-k)}v^{(k)}.$$

Then

$$u=\ln x,u'=x^{-1},u''=-x^{-2},u'''=2!x^{-3},\cdots u^{(n)}=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!x^{-n},$$
$$v=x^2,v'=2x,v''=2,v'''=0,\cdots v^{(n)}=0,$$

and for $n\ge3$, the sum reduces to three terms

$$\binom n0u^{(n)}v+\binom n1u^{(n-1)}v'+\binom n2u^{(n-2)}v''\\
=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!x^{-n}\cdot x^2+n(-1)^{n-2}(n-2)!x^{1-n}\cdot 2x+\frac{n(n-1)}2(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!x^{2-n}\cdot2\\
=((n-1)(n-2)-2n(n-2)+n(n-1)))(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!x^{2-n}\\
=2(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!x^{2-n}.$$

---

Note that the formula doesn't work for $n=2$ even though the Leibnitz development has the three terms. The reason is that

$$u^{(n-2)}=(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!x^{2-n}$$ doesn't hold for $n=2$.

Comment: Thank you for posting such a detailed method! The only thing that I cannot get grasp of is why the equation that we found is for n>= 3 and not for n<=3. Since for n>= 3 v^(n) will give zero, the sum should be zero as well and so that's why we obtain only 3 terms in the expression. However, I do understand that if we consider n<=3 in our final expression, we will get a negative factorial which cannot be true. And so I am not quite sure where did we change to n>=3.

Comment: @blondie: "where did we change to $n\ge3 ?$": what do you mean exactly ? For $n\ge3$, (1) the sum does encompass three terms, (2) which are given bythe above formulas. For $n<3$, one of these two conditions doesn't hold.

Comment: When the sum was reduced to 3 terms, we obtained those terms from (uv)^(3). So, when n <= 3. For n>=3 the sum is zero as v^(n) will give zero. Thus, my confusion is in why we are considering n>=3 whilst effectively we got the three terms from when n<=3.

Comment: Where did you see $n\le3$ and where did you see $(uv)^{(3)}$ in my answer ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Nice derivation.  I think there's a minor typo -- your main formula $$(uv)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nku^{n-k}v^k$$ should be $$(uv)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nku^{(n-k)}v^{(k)}$$ (derivatives, not powers).

Comment: @MitchellSpector: that's right, thanks. I have fixed all the missing ones I saw.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$f^{(iv)}(x)=2\cdot 2x^{-3}$$ and $$f^{(v)}=-2\cdot 2\cdot3x^{-4}$$
can you proceed?